# Switching Console Apps generates a Bad Message 414 reason: URI Too Long

Tags: lightning-web-components, console, lightningnavigation

I have a LWC where I am switching between Console Apps.  Each time I switch, the URL for the Console increases to a point where after about 5 iterations it generates an error.  Is there any way to reset the URL or Page Reference so this doesn't occur?

Navigation Code (Switching to the commented out code has the same behavior)

```
    navigateToAppPage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Get the attributes for the selected App
    var app = this.apps.find(app => app.index == event.target.dataset.key);

    // Navigate to the specified App and App Page for the same Record
    this.appPageRef = {
        type: "standard__app",
        attributes: {
            appTarget: app.name,
            pageRef: {
                type: "standard__recordPage",
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    actionName: "view"
                }
            }
        }            
    }
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.appPageRef)
        .then(url => this.url = url);
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.appPageRef);

    // this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    //     type: "standard__app",
    //     attributes: {
    //         appTarget: app.name,
    //         pageRef: {
    //             type: "standard__recordPage",
    //             attributes: {
    //                 recordId: this.recordId,
    //                 actionName: "view"
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    // })
}
```

The first time I switch Apps this is the URL:

> https://xxx--ersmith.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/5006C000004WenBQAS/view?ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FCase%2F5006C000004WenBQAS%2Fview

The second time I switch away and then back I get this:

> https://xxx--ersmith.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/5006C000004WenBQAS/view?ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FCase%2F5006C000004WenBQAS%2Fview%3Fws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%262.ws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview

The third time:

> https://xxx--ersmith.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/5006C000004WenBQAS/view?ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FCase%2F5006C000004WenBQAS%2Fview%3Fws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%25262.ws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%262.ws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%25262.ws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview

The fourth time:

> https://xxx--ersmith.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/5006C000004WenBQAS/view?ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FCase%2F5006C000004WenBQAS%2Fview%3Fws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25262.ws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%262.ws%3D%252Flightning%252Fr%252FCase%252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252Fview%253Fws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25262.ws%253D%25252Flightning%25252Fr%25252FCase%25252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252Fview%25253Fws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%2525262.ws%25253D%2525252Flightning%2525252Fr%2525252FCase%2525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252Fview%2525253Fws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%252525262.ws%2525253D%252525252Flightning%252525252Fr%252525252FCase%252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%252525252Fview%252525253Fws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview%25252525262.ws%252525253D%25252525252Flightning%25252525252Fr%25252525252FCase%25252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%25252525252Fview%25252525253Fws%25252525253D%2525252525252Flightning%2525252525252Fr%2525252525252FCase%2525252525252F5006C000004WenBQAS%2525252525252Fview

Answer (score 0):

Adding the objectApiName attribute to the pageReference fixed the issue.

```
        type: "standard__app",
        attributes: {
            appTarget: app.name,
            pageRef: {
                type: "standard__recordPage",
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: 'Case',  // Doesn't matter if this Object name doesn't match the Record Id
                    actionName: "view"
                }
            }
        }
```